# Postfix doesn't send emails until after systemctl restart postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I'm been trying to set up smtp postfix on Ubuntu 18.04. I've finally got it so that gmail recipients see SPF and DKIM pass (although it still ends up in the spam folder, not sure why?)

However, when sending emails, it most of the time it doesn't send them until after I restart the process with `sudo systemctl restart postfix`.

When I do `systemctl status postfix`, it says `active (exited)`.

I'm not sure why this is, any ideas? I want the emails to send straight away without me having to restart it like this.

Please let me know if I should provide any other info / files:

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more compl$


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default$
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_$
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_sc$

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc pac$
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenti$
myhostname = [removed].com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost.learn$
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all


# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
compatibility_level = 2
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost.[removed].com, [removed].com, [removed].local, localhost.local, localhost
myhostname = [removed].com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

/var/log/mail.log

```
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/postfix-script[1679]: starting the Postfix mail system
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/master[1681]: daemon started -- version 3.3.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/pickup[1682]: E88CD81E22: uid=0 from=<no-reply@[removed].com>
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] opendkim[1456]: OpenDKIM Filter: mi_stop=1
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] opendkim[1456]: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 terminating with status 0, errno = 0
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: warning: milter local:opendkim/opendkim.sock: can't read SMFIC_OPTNEG reply packet header: Connection reset by peer
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: warning: milter local:opendkim/opendkim.sock: read error in initial handshake
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: E88CD81E22: message-id=<222b02b2-6a3c-3e6f-5083-b9889f5be672@[removed].com>
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] postfix/qmgr[1683]: E88CD81E22: from=<no-reply@[removed].com>, size=1357, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 28 10:18:25 [removed] opendkim[1692]: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 starting (args: -x /etc/opendkim.conf)
Apr 28 10:18:28 [removed] postfix/smtp[1690]: E88CD81E22: to=<[removed]@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c06::1b]:25, delay=545, delays=542/0.01/1.4/1.5, dsn=2.0.0, stat$
Apr 28 10:18:28 [removed] postfix/qmgr[1683]: E88CD81E22: removed
Apr 28 10:19:13 [removed] postfix/pickup[1682]: A30DB81E22: uid=0 from=<no-reply@[removed].com>
Apr 28 10:19:13 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: A30DB81E22: message-id=<2e5c7f36-b481-4815-e666-3f057951f498@[removed].com>
Apr 28 10:19:13 [removed] opendkim[1692]: KeyTable entry for 'default._domainkey.[removed].com' corrupt
Apr 28 10:19:13 [removed] opendkim[1692]: A30DB81E22: error loading key 'default._domainkey.[removed].com'
Apr 28 10:19:13 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: A30DB81E22: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; from=<no-reply@[removed]$
Apr 28 10:19:25 [removed] postfix/pickup[1682]: A71D981E22: uid=0 from=<no-reply@[removed].com>
Apr 28 10:19:25 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: A71D981E22: message-id=<2e5c7f36-b481-4815-e666-3f057951f498@[removed].com>
Apr 28 10:19:25 [removed] opendkim[1692]: KeyTable entry for 'default._domainkey.[removed].com' corrupt
Apr 28 10:19:25 [removed] opendkim[1692]: A71D981E22: error loading key 'default._domainkey.[removed].com'
Apr 28 10:19:25 [removed] postfix/cleanup[1685]: A71D981E22: milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 4.7.1 Service unavailable - try again later; from=<no-reply@[removed]$
```

Comment: You should look into `/var/log/mail.log` also. Anyway: `inet_interfaces = loopback-only` seems not to be what you want...

Comment: Thanks @gerhardd., I've pasted some logs since last restart. I've commented out the ``inet_interfaces`` line, and restarted (is that right?) but it didn't solve the issue unfortunately

Comment: Looks to me as if there is a problem with your milter config. the lines 11 and 12 in the log tell me, that the messages do get delivered to the recipient at gmail. Try to enhance the milter log, and see what's the problem there.

Comment: This looks similar: https://serverfault.com/questions/847138/postfix-milter-reject-end-of-message-from-4-7-1-service-unavailable-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to people who commented, eventually I found [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/opendkim/bugs/120/) which instructed me to comment out certain lines in `/etc/opendkim.conf`:

```js
KeyFile /etc/opendkim/keys/mail.private
#KeyTable /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
#SigningTable /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
```

Then I set up rDNS with the PTR record. Now, the emails are sent immediately without needing to do restarts, and I get perfect 10/10 scores on mail-tester